# Symfony EasyAdminBundle 3 override the createIndexQueryBuilder()

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

It said on the EasyAdminBundle doc

> For example, the index() action calls to a method named createIndexQueryBuilder() to create the Doctrine query builder used to get the results displayed on the index listing. If you want to customize that listing, it’s better to override the createIndexQueryBuilder() method instead of the entire index() method.

So let's imagine I have in my user entity the field isDeleted set to true when the user is deleted. In the index page, I want to display only user with isDeleted = false.
How to override the createIndexQueryBuilder() for this purpose?

Here is the method createIndexQueryBuilder

```
public function createIndexQueryBuilder(SearchDto $searchDto, EntityDto $entityDto, FieldCollection $fields, FilterCollection $filters): QueryBuilder
{
    return $this->get(EntityRepository::class)->createQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters);
}
```

I tried to override it like this but it didn't work

```
public function createIndexQueryBuilder(SearchDto $searchDto, EntityDto $entityDto, FieldCollection $fields, FilterCollection $filters): QueryBuilder
{
    $response = $this->get(EntityRepository::class)->createQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters);
    $response->where('isDeleted', true);
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Not seeing code hope you doing well too

Comment: Have you override this method ? I have the same problem. Place your crud controller code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All you need is add `entity.` in where clause :)

```
public function createIndexQueryBuilder(SearchDto $searchDto, EntityDto $entityDto, FieldCollection $fields, FilterCollection $filters): QueryBuilder
{
    parent::createIndexQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters);

    $response = $this->get(EntityRepository::class)->createQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters);
    $response->where('entity.isDeleted = 1');

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: I would say the parent call is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, as @KaizokuGambare comment says the parent call did not change anything for me. However the search would crash when using `$response->where` setting this to `$response->andWhere` got everything to work properly.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me with EasyAdmin 4.x

```
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Orm\EntityRepository;

class CampaignCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public function __construct(EntityRepository $entityRepository)
    {
        $this->entityRepository = $entityRepository;
    }

    public function createIndexQueryBuilder(SearchDto $searchDto, EntityDto $entityDto, FieldCollection $fields, FilterCollection $filters): ORMQueryBuilder
    {
        $response = $this->entityRepository->createQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters);
        $response->andWhere('entity.user = :user')->setParameter('user', $this->getUser());

        return $response;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

EasyAdmin4 solution

*Note: The keyword (alias) `entity` is important*

```
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;

class ArticleCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
     ...

     public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
     {
          return [
                ...
                AssociationField::new('author')->setQueryBuilder(
                fn (QueryBuilder $queryBuilder) => $queryBuilder
                   ->leftJoin('entity.article', 'a')
                   ->andWhere('entity.isActive = 1')
                   ->andWhere('a.author is NULL')
                  ),
                ...
            ]
      }

      ...
}
```

Comment: This answers a different question I had about EA4. 
Did not know that you could do that for AssociationField - nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an exemple about how to replace the DQL FILTER in EasyAdmin v3.x

**EasyAdmin v2.x  DQL FILTER :**

```
easy_admin:
  entities:
    User:
      class: App\Entity\User
      list:
        dql_filter: "entity.roles NOT LIKE '%%ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN%%'"
```

**EasyAdmin v3.x  inside UserCrudController :**

```
public function createIndexQueryBuilder(SearchDto $searchDto, EntityDto $entityDto, FieldCollection $fields, FilterCollection $filters): QueryBuilder
{
    $response = $this->get(EntityRepository::class)->createQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters);
    $response->where("entity.roles NOT LIKE '%%ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN%%'");

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: I have this exact requirement where I only want to show a specific user role in an EasyAdminCrud. Is THIS the only way of doing it? A LIKE query?

Answer (score 1):

For everyone getting following QueryException using the accepted answer and finding this through search:

```
QueryException 
Too many parameters: the query defines 1 parameters and you bound 3
```

**EasyAdmin v3.x inside your EntityCrudController:**

- use **->andWhere()** function
- use **entity.** as prefix (really, use "entity", do not replace by your entity-name)

```
public function createIndexQueryBuilder(SearchDto $searchDto, EntityDto $entityDto, FieldCollection $fields, FilterCollection $filters): QueryBuilder
{
    $response = $this->get(EntityRepository::class)->createQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters);
    $response->andWhere('entity.isDeleted = 1');   
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that when we are searching with the filter input, we have the following error : `Too few parameters: the query defines 4 parameters but you only bound 2`. Without the **createIndexQueryBuilder** customization, we haven't :/

Answer (score 0):

With EasyAdmin 4, i've found this solution, because I was having an error with get(EntityRepository).
Since you get "parent", you get already your Entity and Repository.

```
$response = parent::createIndexQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters);
$response->andWhere('entity.status = :status')->setParameter('status', $status);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another fictional example for EasyAdmin 3.x, adding a filter on entities loaded in an edit subfield. These entities are the target of a OneToMany relation (Showroom::gears), based on a join with the current Showroom entity's other attributes (Showroom::creator is the same Member entity as the owner of the Gear::inventory) :

```php
class ShowroomCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Showroom::class;
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        
        return [
            IdField::new('id')->hideOnForm(),
            // relation to Member entity
            AssociationField::new('creator'),
            BooleanField::new('published')
                ->onlyOnForms()
                ->hideWhenCreating(),
            TextField::new('description'),
            AssociationField::new('gears')
                ->onlyOnForms()
                // we don't want to manage association between gears and the showroom upon showroom creation
                ->hideWhenCreating()
                ->setTemplatePath('admin/fields/inventory_gears.html.twig')
                // Only display gears that belong to the inventory of the showroom creator
                ->setQueryBuilder(
                    function (QueryBuilder $queryBuilder) {
                        // get current showroom instance
                        $currentShowroom = $this->getContext()->getEntity()->getInstance();
                        $creator = $currentShowroom->getCreator();
                        $memberId = $creator->getId();
                        // load the gears whose inventory owner is the showroom creator only
                        $queryBuilder->leftJoin('entity.inventory', 'i')
                            ->leftJoin('i.owner', 'm')
                            ->andWhere('m.id = :member_id')
                            ->setParameter('member_id', $memberId);    
                        return $queryBuilder;
                    }
                   ),
        ];
    }
```