# EasyAdmin3 static dql filters

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin3

I need to filter the results of an index page by default so that it only returns entities that meet a certain condition, without the user actively filtering anything. EasyAdminBundle2 documentation seems to have an answer with [static filters](https://symfony.com/doc/2.x/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/list-search-show-configuration.html#filtering-results).
However, I can't seem to find the option in EasyAdminBundle3. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the easyadmin 2 -> 3 migration guide (https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/upgrade.html)

> The dql_filter option to quickly filter the entity listings has been
> removed. Instead, use the createIndexQueryBuilder() method in the CRUD
> controller.

There is also a related SO question with code examples: [Symfony EasyAdminBundle 3 override the createIndexQueryBuilder()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63432424/symfony-easyadminbundle-3-override-the-createindexquerybuilder)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so i use the answer instead :
You can use

```
 public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
  
        AssociationField::new('randomField'),
        TextField::new('randomField2'),
       /////////
    }

     public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
        {
            return $crud
                ->setDefaultSort(['id' => 'DESC'])
      
            ;
        }
```

In this example, ->setDefaultSort will sort by default the id of your item  by DESC.

Comment: Thank you, but that would sort records, and wont filter them